# certbot-auto: No such file or directory

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate, certbot, renewal

Can someone help me please, Im trying to renew my certificate using google console these are my steps.

1.) sudo service httpd stop

2.) ./certbot-auto certonly --force-renewal -w /home/tsibog/public_html/ -d tsibog.app -d [www.tsibog.app](http://www.tsibog.app)

3.) sudo service httpd start

It produced this output:

-bash: ./certbot-auto: No such file or directory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOJi4.png)

It worked before many times but now it isn't. Please help, thank you in advance